# defaultdict slower in comparison to normal dictionary

Tags: python

I have a very simple code and was testing it with normal dictonaries as well as `defaultdict` and surprisingly `defaultdict` is slower when compared with normal dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from timeit import timeit

text = "hello this is python python is a great language, hello again"
d = defaultdict(int)
s = {}


def defdict():
    global text, d
    for word in text.split():
        d[word] += 1


def nordict():
    global text, s
    for word in text.split():
        if word not in s:
            s[word] = 1
        else:
            s[word] += 1

print(timeit(stmt='defdict', setup='from __main__ import defdict', number=3))
print(timeit(stmt='nordict', setup='from __main__ import nordict', number=3))

st = time.time()
defdict()
print(time.time() - st)

st = time.time()
nordict()
print(time.time() - st)
```

***Output***

```
5.799811333417892e-07
3.5099219530820847e-07
6.198883056640625e-06
3.0994415283203125e-06
```

This is a very simple example and for this particular case i can surely use `Counter` which would fastest of all, but I am looking at it from overall perspective for cases where we need to do stuff just more than counting the occurrences of a key and where we obviously cannot use `Counter`.

So why I am seeing is this behavior, am i missing something here or doing something in a wrong way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test is flawed because of the small size of the string. Thus fixed costs can outweigh the performance of your iteration logic. A good hint is your timings are measured in microseconds, negligible for benchmarking purposes.

Here's a more reasonable test:

```
n = 10**5
text = "hello this is python python is a great language, hello again"*n

%timeit defdict()  # 445 ms per loop
%timeit nordict()  # 520 ms per loop
```

Comment: In my opinion, while this is definitely a better test for the reasons stated, it's really only showing the performance when there a few cases where the key isn't already in the dictionary. An even better, although harder to write, one would need to simulate many more missing/new key cases, probably in a statically random sense. Alternatively, the OP may information about the expected number of times keys can be expected to already be there, in which a case suitable test scenario could be used.